# WillPopScope is deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to exit the alert.

```dart
WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          final shouldExit = await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Exit App'),
              content: const Text('Are you sure you want to exit the app?'),
              actions: [
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                  child: const Text('Dismiss'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                  child: Text(
                    'Exit',
                    style:
                    TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );

          return shouldExit;
        },
```

Comment: Please take a look here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138614

Answer (score 4):

```
PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
          debugPrint("didPop1: $didPop");
          if (didPop) {
            return;
          }
          
          final bool? shouldPop = await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Exit App'),
              content: const Text('Are you sure you want to exit the app?'),
              actions: [
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                  child: const Text('Dismiss'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                  child: Text(
                    'Exit',
                    style:
                    TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );

          if (shouldPop ?? false) {
            SystemNavigator.pop();
          }
          debugPrint("didPop2: $didPop");
        },
```

Comment: In my case onPopInvoked() does not get called when canPop is true.  Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution

```dart
 PopScope(
        canPop: false,
        onPopInvoked: (bool value) async {
          final shouldExit = await showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Exit App'),
              content: const Text('Are you sure you want to exit the app?'),
              actions: [
                CupertinoDialogAction(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                  child: const Text('Dismiss'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, true),
                  child: Text(
                    'Exit',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
          if (shouldExit == true) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          }
        },
```