# PopScope returning Failed assertion: line 5238 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true in Flutter 3.16.1

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I would need to conditionally navigate to a screen and hence was using `WillPopScope` widget wrapped around the `Scaffold` widget in my app.

**Code:**

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (hasProfilePicUpdated) {
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            Routes.dashboard,
            (route) => false,
            arguments: DashboardArgumentModel(
              onboardingState: dashboardArgumentModel.onboardingState,
            ).toMap(),
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
```

With the code above, I was able to navigate to my desired screen. Now after I upgraded Flutter to 3.16.1, I got a warning that `WillPopScope` is deprecated and that I should use `PopScope`. Hence, I updated my code to as below:

**Code:**

```
PopScope(
      // canPop: true, - this makes no difference
      onPopInvoked: (val) async {
        if (hasProfilePicUpdated) {
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            Routes.dashboard,
            (route) => false,
            arguments: DashboardArgumentModel(
              onboardingState: dashboardArgumentModel.onboardingState,
            ).toMap(),
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
```

**Issue**:

However, the code using PopScope gives me the following error when I click on the back button:

**[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5238 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.**

I have tried

- wrapping the `Navigator.pop(context)` in a `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)`
- adding a `Future.delayed()` before `Navigator.pop(context)` but keep facing the same issue.

**Request**:

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong in my code which is preventing me from implementing the desired behaviour using PopScope and how to rectify the error.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer given at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77529346/19413610

it turns out that I needed to return from the function if the boolean parameter to the onPopInvoked function returns true. Below is the functioning code:

```
PopScope(
          onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
            if (didPop) {
              return;
            }
            if (hasProfilePicUpdated) {
              Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                Routes.dashboard,
                (route) => false,
                arguments: DashboardArgumentModel(
                  onboardingState: dashboardArgumentModel.onboardingState,
                ).toMap(),
              );
            } else {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          },
          child: Scaffold(
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() method to delay the call to Navigator.pop() until after the current frame has been rendered.

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  });
```

Comment: When I do this, the pop happens but I'm taken to a black screen.

Comment: So you can add bool value in pop like Navigator.pop(context, result);